# R stat_function with alternative dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've reviewed what's here on stat_function and I still can't get this to work. Here's min working code:

```
plotdata <- cbind(as.data.frame(seq(-5, 5, length=10)), as.data.frame(-seq(-5, 5, length=10)))
colnames(plotdata) <- c('x', 'y')

xvalues <- as.data.frame(seq(-5, 5, length = 100))
colnames(xvalues) <- 'x'

xey <- function(x) {x}

#ggplot(plotdata, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + stat_function(data=xvalues, fun = xey, linetype = 2)

ggplot(plotdata, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + stat_function(mapping = aes(x = x), data=xvalues, fun = xey, linetype = 2)
```

The error I get is :

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

As you can see, I've tried it both with mapping and without and the error is the same. The plot works without the stat_function, the xey function is vectorised and written in terms of x, and the xvalues column is labeled x, so ????

EDIT - added naming column in xvalues, didn't transfer from my notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt a `stat_function` issue. You dont have a column called `y` the dataset you pass into the `ggplot` function. Changing the `data` parameter value fixes the problem.

```
ggplot(plotdata, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + stat_function(mapping = aes(x = x), data=plotdata, fun = xey, linetype = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Rilcon! Ah, a problem with putting together a minimum working example. Pls imagine that xvalues is different from the values in plotdata. I want the stat_function to plot on a DIFFERENT dataset, consisting only of x values, than plotdata. Thank you so much for your attention to my question.

Comment: the inputs to `stat_function` must be either an equation or `x,y` pairs, it looks like you are passing it only `x` values.

Comment: The  x = x  is from the example for stat_plots out of the documentation, which doesn't use a y. But I tried x = x, y = 0 in mapping and it worked!

Comment: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3365_9573f6d661b444499365fe1841ee65d3.html   here's what I referring to with the x only. Rilcon, by putting y = 0 into the mapping I can now plot what I want. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Awesome, would you accept the answer if it helped, so we can get it out of the unanswered question queue?

Comment: Yes, I'd love to accept your answer. It really did help. Could you edit the answer to include the bit about setting mapping to (x=x, y= 0)? I didn't find that anywhere, and technically your answer as posted suggests using the same dataset for both, not different data sets.